# Slack notification does not trigger on custom tag

Tags: python, graphql, sentry

i'm trying to log a new custom tag with the name `project` but in the slack notification just appear the original tags (like logger),

In sentry if I put:
[image: Sentry]

[image: Slack___capek-dev___Capek___1_nuevo_elemento]

- *doesn't work ^*

but if use  a `logger` tag:
[image: Sentry]

[image: Slack___capek-dev___Capek]

- *`logger` is a custom tag, works fine! ^*

### creating a custom tag

*Mode 1*

i'm working on python with flask and try to create the custom tag on that way:

[image: Untitled-1_—_renovacion-urbana-full-stack]

*Mode 2*

[image: Untitled-1_—_renovacion-urbana-full-stack]

neither of these cases work for me, what i'm doing bad?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need put the environment in the init function.

look at here https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/501